# Global name is not defined when importing python module

Tags: python, module

I have a function in orbital.py:

```
def get_data(stock):
    yahoodata = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock,start,end)
    return yahoodata

!jupyter nbconvert --to script orbital.ipynb
```

And in a seperate notebook, I import the module from above:

```
import orbital
from orbital import *

start = dt.date(2007,1,1)
end = dt.date.today()
stock = ['AAPL','TSLA]
get_data(stock)
```

But get the following error:

```
NameError: global name 'start' is not defined
```

Not sure what to do , my expected output would be able to flexibly change start and end in the second notebook , and use the get_data function I imported from the orbital.py file.

Comment: Is this your code? There is a function accepting one parameter but seems to have access to 3.

Comment: When you import something it does not mean that the namespace are combined, `start` will not be available to the imported function. The way to solve it is to add the arguments `start` and `end` to the function and hand them over when calling.

Comment: when I do get_data(stock,start,end) I get the same error

Comment: Klaus - how do i do that?

Comment: global variable scope only applies to the variables in a module (file). Think about how much this would pollute the global namespace if this wasn't the case!

Comment: Error message says it all: You don't have access to `start`. Either declare it as global, or pass it in as parameter to `get_data` function.

Comment: `def get_data(stock, start, end):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `get_data` accepts one parameter. It does not have access to `start` and `end` as they are not in the same namespace and therefore not accessible. You'll need to *pass* those variables as parameters to your function:

`orbital.py`:

```
def get_data(stock, start, end): # receiving those variables here
    yahoodata = pdr.get_data_yahoo(stock, start, end)
    return yahoodata
```

`Notebook`:

```
...
df = get_data(stock, start, end) # passing those variables here
```

Comment: ---> 49 def get_data(stock, start, end):

Comment: ---> NameError: global name 'start' is not defined

Comment: @thomas.mac It appears you're doing something more besides what's here, because that does _not_ happen normally. I'll need to see your full code listing.